# Is there any way to read a cypress fixture with a variable?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have written a config.json file in fixtures which have the below given data:

```
 {"username" : "test", "password" : "test@123"}
```

To fetch the values I have written the below code in a page.js under Utils:

```
cy.page = {
    getValueFromPropertyFile: (field) => {
        cy.fixture('config').then(function (data) {
            this.data = data
            return this.data.field
        })
    }
}
```

But, when I am calling this function like this in a test:

```
cy.page.getValueFromPropertyFile('username')
```

I am getting undefined because it's not fetching the value of 'username' in config but is searching for the word 'field' itself.

Is there a way to make this work and let it use the value of field instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing the name of the field, use square brackets to access the value

```js
cy.page = {
  getValueFromPropertyFile: (field) => {
    cy.fixture('config').then(function (data) {
        this.data = data
        return this.data[field]  // change this line
    })
  }
}
```

But the `cy.fixture()` call is asynchronous (it has to read from the disk).

You would be better returning the result of the fixture itself,

```js
cy.page = {
  getValueFromPropertyFile: (field) => {
    return cy.fixture('config').then(function (data) {
        this.data = data
        return this.data[field]  
    })
  }
}

cy.page.getValueFromPropertyFile('username').then(userName => {

  // accessed from inside .then() because of async call in method

})
```

---

Since you set `this.data = data` you could change the function to just load up the data, then pick the individual fields from the `cy.page.data`

```js
cy.page = {
  loadData: () => {
    cy.fixture('config').then(function (data) {
        this.data = data
    })
  }
}

cy.page.loadData()
// use fields
console.log(cy.page.data.username)
```

Comment: The second approach is working for me, but can we club 'then' with the function itself in any way to reduce extra effort each time fetching a value, 
Something like this:
`cy.pageBase = {
    getValueFromPropertyFile: (field) => {
      cy.fixture('config').then(function (data) {
            this.data = data
           this.data[field]
       }).then(field => {
           return field
       })
    }
}
`

Comment: I was thinking about that, see additional code for another approach. Not sure if there might be a race condition but it's worth a try.